# Variable not printing in python

Tags: python, string, variables

I have an array of strings that I am trying to iterate through and store the string into another string. When I write this to another file, though, it comes out as %s.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
for labels in rows[0]:
    if (labels == 'Year'):
        continue
    else:
        dataset = """{{\nlabel: '%s',\ndata: '%s',\nbackgroundColor: 'rgba(168, 191, 18, 0.7)',\nborderColor: 'rgba(168, 191, 18, 1)',\nborderWidth: 0\n}},\n""" % labels, labels
        f.write(dataset)
f.close()
```

Also, I was not sure how to split the dataset line into multiple lines while still keeping the formatting that it should. Can someone please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Tried your code. It prints `not enough arguments for format string`.
Try `% (labels, labels)`

Comment: first `labels` is probably taken into account, and `dataset` is becoming an array => [ `big string`, `labels` ]